# possible number of PAN card numbers

Tags: permutations, combinations

Permanent Account Number (PAN) is a code that acts as identification of Indians. An example number would be in the form of **AAAPL1234C**. The format is

- The first three letters are sequence of alphabets from AAA to ZZZ
- The fourth character informs about the type of holder of the card (possible letters A, B, C, F, G, H, L, J, P, T, K)
- The fifth character of the PAN is the first character

  - of the surname or last name of the person, in the case of a "Personal" PAN card
  - of the name of the Entity, Trust, society, or organisation in the case of Company/ HUF/ Firm/ AOP/ BOI/ Local Authority/ Artificial Judicial Person/ Govt
- next four numbers are ranging from 0001 to 9999
- The last character is an alphabetic check digit

reference: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_account_number)

Now, I'm trying to find the total possible number of PAN numbers like below

1. for first 3 alphabets - 26 * 26 * 26
2. fourth letter have only 11 possiblities - 11
3. fifth letter can be any of the 26 alphabets - 26
4. next 4 letters are between 0001 to 9999 - 9999
5. last letter can be any of the 26 aplhabets - 26

so total would be 26 * 26 * 26 * 11 * 26 * 9999 * 26.

is this correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything you say is true, then yes you are correct. I just have concerns about items 4. and 5.

4. You are correct if these four numbers are any numbers $0001$ to $9999$. There are $9999$ possible numbers. *However*, it is possible that the first three digits are any value $0$ to $9$ **and** the last digit is any value $1$ to $9$. In this case there are $10\times10\times10\times9 = 9000$ ways to fill out these four digits. This case excludes all values that end in $0$, like $10, 100, 1000$, etc.
5. It is possible that there is some algorithm to calculate this "alphabetic check", so it might not be true that all 26 letters are possible.

I do not believe the article addressed these two items. If we simply ignore them and assume that your understanding of the structure is correct, then your calculation is correct.

Comment: the 4 digit number can be any number from 0001 to 9999. but if we exclude 0 for last digit then we are excluding all the numbers, including 0000, that ends with 0 i.e 0010, 0020, 0030 and so on. which we shouldn't i guess. so we can assume 9999.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is $26 \cdot 26 \cdot 26 \cdot 11 \cdot 26 \cdot 9999$ because last digit is not controllable and for precious 9 digit you will not find different value of 10th digit for same 9 digit